# Detect disconnect from named pipe in linux

Tags: c++, linux, named-pipes

I work on an C++ project in Linux where two programs communicate over a named pipe.

Now I want to detect in one program if the other disconnects from the named pipe.

Is there a way to detect the disconnect?

**Edit**

I opened the fifo in O_RDWR mode - that was the reason that select didn't react on the disconnect. Now I open the fifo with (O_RDONLY | O_NDELAY) and all works fine.

Comment: How are you making the named pipe and what have you tried so far?

Comment: The pipe is created with "mkfifo". Then I wait (with "select") for data from the other side. The Protocol don't allow me to send a ping or something like that.

Comment: This is well-documented. I find it hard to believe that you've done any research....

Comment: Thanks for the replys.. i think i asked the wrong question. the actual question is: is there a way to detect a disconnect within a select call and without explicit calling "read" or "write"..

Comment: select will still tickle the read socket set and you can read the appropriate set socket. Then check for 0 and errno etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is same as in TCP/IP. You need to attempt to read data, if that fails with 0, pipe is closed.

read and recv:

> These  calls  return  the  number  of bytes received, or -1 if an error
>          occurred.  **The return value will be 0 when the peer  has  performed  an
>          orderly shutdown**.

There is also `SIGPIPE` signal. It'll be sent when you try write to a broken pipe - pipe with no readers.

Answer (score 1):

If `read` on one end returns with 0 bytes, the pipe is disconnected.